# How to navigate to a specific page in tab navigator from a nested stack navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a switch navigator with one stack and a tab navigator inside my tab navigator I have another stack.
What I want to do is navigate from my tabs navigator stack navigator to a screen in my tab navigator, please keep in mind that I'm not using redux.
This image will explain a little about what I'm trying to achieve here:
[image]

Comment: did you happen to solve this?

Comment: yes, I did it but its not the proper way, I have used react native event listener package and listened for the events